# SwifUI - how can you make the selected item in a List show the default selection color

Tags: list, swiftui

When you select a list item in a list, it defaults to blue.  I have persisted many of the details of the app in a property file to restore certain aspects on re-launch.  One restoration is to automatically re-select the last item selected in a list.

This works fine - but the background is grey and not the default blue - is there anyway to force the color of the entire list item (which has a navigation item and text in it) to blue ?

```
  List(selection: $panel){
   ForEach(dashboardSections) { section in
    Section(header: Text(section.name)){
     ForEach(section.widgets) { widget in
      NavigationLink(value: widget.panel){
       showBadge(widget: widget)   
      }
      .disabled(widget.disabled)
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

panel is re-populated at launch, and that works, but the background is grey.

Just added screen shots for clarity:

[After re-selecting list item on re-launch, color is grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBKgM.png)

[Initial selection, the default behavior, color is blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9sbM.png)

Comment: Can you add more information? Like what is that dashboardSections struct / class. Can you include all of the structs?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this function:

```
    func GetBackgroundColor() -> Color{
        var returnColor = Color.blue.opacity(0)
        dashboardSections.forEach { section in
            guard let panel = panel else { return } // You can delete this line if the panel variable is not an optional.
            if item == selected{
                returnColor = .blue
            }
        }
        return returnColor
    }
```

And you will need to change your code to this:

```
  List(selection: $panel){
       ForEach(dashboardSections) { section in
           Section(header: Text(section.name)){
               ForEach(section.widgets) { widget in
                   NavigationLink(value: widget.panel){
                       showBadge(widget: widget)   
                   }
                   .disabled(widget.disabled)
               }
           }
           .listRowBackground(GetBackgroundColor())
      }
  }
```

I hope this helped. If there is any errors, can you include them in the question?

Comment: Thanks for that example ... I had something similar, which I merge with yours ... as follows:      .listRowBackground((widget.panel == panel) ? Color.blue : Color.clear), but while that did work, the highlight is the entire list area and its square in nature, versus when you select, it is not entire area and has rounded edges.

Comment: And I can't add a screen shot or more content easily, as when I hit enter, it auto submits.